# What is this warning message all about?

Tags: certificate

Why is it so that every time when i start "FireFox", this message pops up:

> advisordb.wmtransfer.com: 443 uses an
>   invalid security cetificate. The
>   certificate is not trusted because the
>   issuer certificate is not trusted.
>   (Error code:
>   sec_error_untrusted_issuer)

I guess it has to do with "WebMoney" that I had installed on my computer. But I have already uninstalled it, yet this message still pops up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then there's something on your system trying to connect to WebMoney. Although adding the security certificate as an exception would indeed make the message go away, I would be more concerned with whatever is making the connection.

Is your homepage Webmoney? If not, consider getting some anti-spyware tools or checking a [Hijackthis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) log for referrences to Webmoney.

---

Edit: Following the log you have posted in comments, it looks like this entry could be responsible for the phantom webmoney connections:

```
O16 - DPF: {463ED66E-431B-11D2-ADB0-0080C83DA4EB} (AcceptWM Class) - https://w3s.webmoney.ru/WMAcceptor.dll
```

You do seem to have other issues though.

Based on [this](http://www.fileresearchcenter.com/A/ALIBABAR.DLL-7543.html) site, I would remove all referrences to "alibabar", as it appears to be trojan or trojan-like.

```
O8 - Extra context menu item: ¨Ï¥Î¨³¹pÂ÷½u¤U¸ü - C:\Program Files\Thunder Network\Thunder\Program\OfflineDownload.htm
O8 - Extra context menu item: °Å¶KÃ¯¤å¦r:  Â² > Ác - res://C:\Program Files\ALiBaBar\ALiBaBar.dll/RT_HTML/ClipToTrad
O8 - Extra context menu item: °Å¶KÃ¯¤å¦r:  Ác > Â² - res://C:\Program Files\ALiBaBar\ALiBaBar.dll/RT_HTML/ClipToSim
```

There's various references to Thunder Network/Thunder AtOnce. If you do not use this application, you should remove the entries.

My Taiwanese isn't that great, so I have no idea what this is;

```
O16 - DPF: {2B38E40E-977D-4767-919C-2AA29C041618} (BOT Class) - https://ebank.bot.com.tw/NNBank/NN/FCardS.CAB
```

If you don't use https://ebank.bot.com.tw, you should remove this entry.

These are app-helpers for PowerDVD, Adobe, Quicktime, and Java. You don't need them loading at start up.

```
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [RemoteControl] "C:\Program Files\CyberLink\PowerDVD\PDVDServ.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [Adobe Reader Speed Launcher] "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\Reader_sl.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [SunJavaUpdateSched] "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_02\bin\jusched.exe"
O4 - HKLM\..\Run: [QuickTime Task] "C:\Program Files\QuickTime\qttask.exe" -atboottime
```

Comment: Hello BlueNovember!!! Thanks for responding. I have just downloaded Hijackthis and did a system scan. Here is the log: http://roundcan.narod.ru/hijackthis.log  
Can You, please, take a look at it

Comment: Hey Brilliant. I editted my answer with my comments on your log file. Hope this helps!

Comment: WOW!!!!! BlueNovember, thank You VERY VERY MUCH!!!!!! Too bad my reputation is still not 15 points, so I can't vote up for your answer yet. I'll be sure to do that as soon as I am able.

Comment: @brilliant: there you go :)

Comment: @brilliant +1 for your brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

it's the Error Message when the certificate is not trusted because it is self signed. Self-signed certificates make your data safe from eavesdroppers, but say nothing about who the recipient of the data is. This is common for intranet websites that aren't available publicly.

when the error page shown.

on the page Click on " or Add an Exception"
. Box Pops Up — in the box click on " Get a certificate " . Certificate will be added and click " verify the certificate "

if not you can add an exception for it. Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Encryption -> View certificates -> Servers -> Add exception -> and adding `advisordb.wmtransfer.com:443` (the site you'd stated).

Comment: Thank You, mgpyone, for this input. I'll try to use HiackIt first (advice given to me here by BlueNovember), and then, if it doesn't work, I'll follow up on Your instructions.